# How i get specific data on xml file?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

How i get specific data only Kod attribute is USD and GBP on xml file?Is there a method for fetching attribute value?

TODAY.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-9"?>
    <Tarih_Date Tarih="27.07.2012" Date="07/27/2012">
        <Currency Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD">
            <CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
            <ForexBuying>1.81</ForexBuying>
            <ForexSelling>1.8187</ForexSelling>
        </Currency>
        <Currency Kod="EUR" CurrencyCode="EUR">
            <CurrencyName>EURO</CurrencyName>
            <ForexBuying>2.2227</ForexBuying>
            <ForexSelling>2.2334</ForexSelling>
        </Currency>
        <Currency Kod="GBP" CurrencyCode="GBP">
            <CurrencyName>POUND STERLING</CurrencyName>
            <ForexBuying>2.841</ForexBuying>
            <ForexSelling>2.8559</ForexSelling>
        </Currency>
    </Tarih_Date>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $get_url = "today.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($get_url) or die("Error : Cannot create object!");

    foreach($xml-> Currency as $currency){
         //$attr = $currency -> attributes();
         echo $attr."<br/>";
         //echo $currency -> CurrencyName;
        //echo $data -> CurrencyName ."-". $data -> ForexBuying ."-". $data -> ForexSelling ."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You might want to look into DOMDocument and DOMXpath instead of SimpleXML.

Comment: It's possible to do with SimpleXML, but read these first: [http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576773/how-to-get-attribute-of-node-with-namespace-using-simplexml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576773/how-to-get-attribute-of-node-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use an XPath expression like this:**:

```
/*/*[@Kod = 'USD' or @Kod = 'GBP']/*
```

This selects any element that is a grand-child of the top element of the XML document, and its parent's `Kod` attribute has string value either `"USD"` or `"GBP"`.

**Or use**:

```
/*/*[@Kod = 'USD' or @Kod = 'GBP']/*/text()
```

This selects the text-node children of the elements selected in the previous XPath expression.

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[@Kod = 'USD' or @Kod = 'GBP']/*"/>
===========
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[@Kod = 'USD' or @Kod = 'GBP']/*/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Tarih_Date Tarih="27.07.2012" Date="07/27/2012">
    <Currency Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD">
        <CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
        <ForexBuying>1.81</ForexBuying>
        <ForexSelling>1.8187</ForexSelling>
    </Currency>
    <Currency Kod="EUR" CurrencyCode="EUR">
        <CurrencyName>EURO</CurrencyName>
        <ForexBuying>2.2227</ForexBuying>
        <ForexSelling>2.2334</ForexSelling>
    </Currency>
    <Currency Kod="GBP" CurrencyCode="GBP">
        <CurrencyName>POUND STERLING</CurrencyName>
        <ForexBuying>2.841</ForexBuying>
        <ForexSelling>2.8559</ForexSelling>
    </Currency>
</Tarih_Date>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the results of this evaluation are copied to the output:**

```
<CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
<ForexBuying>1.81</ForexBuying>
<ForexSelling>1.8187</ForexSelling>
<CurrencyName>POUND STERLING</CurrencyName>
<ForexBuying>2.841</ForexBuying>
<ForexSelling>2.8559</ForexSelling>
===========
     US DOLLAR1.811.8187POUND STERLING2.8412.8559
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried get values with index number.Thanks @GordonM.

```
   <?php
        $get_url = "http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($get_url) or die("Error : Cannot create object!");                       
        echo $xml -> Currency[0] -> Isim;
        echo "<br/>";   
        echo $xml -> Currency[2] -> Isim;                   
    ?>
```