# How do I correctly parse a namecheap api xml return?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to parse the following sanitized api response from namecheap:

```
<ApiResponse xmlns="http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response" Status="OK">
    <Errors/>
    <Warnings/>
    <RequestedCommand>namecheap.domains.getlist</RequestedCommand>
    <CommandResponse Type="namecheap.domains.getList">
        <DomainGetListResult>
            <Domain ID="########" Name="website1.com" User="user1" Created="08/18/2014" Expires="08/18/2016" IsExpired="false" IsLocked="false" AutoRenew="false" WhoisGuard="NOTPRESENT"/>
            <Domain ID="########" Name="website2.com" User="user1" Created="08/25/2015" Expires="08/24/2016" IsExpired="false" IsLocked="false" AutoRenew="false" WhoisGuard="NOTPRESENT"/>

        </DomainGetListResult>
        <Paging>
            <TotalItems>2</TotalItems>
            <CurrentPage>1</CurrentPage>
            <PageSize>20</PageSize>
        </Paging>
    </CommandResponse>
    <Server>Servername</Server>
    <GMTTimeDifference>--4:00</GMTTimeDifference>
    <ExecutionTime>0.034</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>
```

This is the closest I've got so far, but it's still not it.

```
$url="https://api.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser=user1&ApiKey=StackExchangeRocks&UserName=user1&Command=namecheap.domains.getList&ClientIp=127.0.0.1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach ($xml->CommandResponse->DomainGetListResult->Domain as $domain) {
   echo $domain->Name, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Almost anything I do is met with an error stating an object isn't found or with no response at all.

All I need to do is be able to extract the domain names to be able to store them in a database. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get en error when you load the XML (something handled like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp))?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576773/how-to-get-attribute-of-node-with-namespace-using-simplexml.

Comment: The xml comes through fine using a web browser, and ghost's tip isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not had the pleasure (yet) to use this extensively PHP *does* support the Document Object Model.

https://php.net/dom