# PHP - SimpleXML missing self-closing, colon-containing tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to parse an xml feed, something like...

*(brief excerpt from Chrome output)*

```
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
     xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
     xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
     xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">

    <channel>
        <title>Title</title>
        <atom:link href="http://thelink.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <link>http://thelink.com </link>

        ... more tags            

        <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
        <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
```

I go about loading the feed in the usual way...

```
$tmp = trim(file_get_contents($tfurl)); // You'd be surprised how many need the trim...
$feed = @simplexml_load_string($tmp, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

But when I print it out via an AJAX call...

*JS*

```
$('pre.results').html(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(msg), null, 4));
```

All the tags with colons are missing...

```
@attributes    
|    version  ........  "2.0"

channel    
|    title  ..........  "Title"
|    link  ...........  "http://thelink.com"
|    lastBuildDate  ..  "Mon, 25 Jul 2016 16:54:06 +0000"
|    language  .......  "en-US"
|    generator  ......  "https://wordpress.org/?v=4.5.3"

... and so on
```

Handling tags with colons is [well documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575788/php-library-for-parsing-xml-with-a-colons-in-tag-names) all over the place, but chasing the tag returns undefined...

```
$channel = $feed->channel;
$link = $channel->children('atom', true)->link; // Fails, undefined
```

While a regular call to a regular tag works fine...

```
$link = $channel->link; // Successful
```

I've tried [adding multiple options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php#101594) to `simplexml_load_string`...

```
$feed = @simplexml_load_string($tmp, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Is there a setting that needs to be changed, or something else that I'm missing?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576773/how-to-get-attribute-of-node-with-namespace-using-simplexml

Comment: When you say "Fails, undefined" on your attempt to use `->children()`, how are you checking the result? Does `echo $link->asXML()` give anything useful? For instance, `echo $link` alone will give you nothing, because it's an empty tag, so there's no content to echo.

Comment: Also, as a tip, and contrary to some tutorials I've seen, it's the URI `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` you should be hard-coding, not the `'atom'` prefix. It's perfectly possible for someone to bind the same URI to a different prefix, maybe even just an auto-generated one like `ns3`, and your code would break (once you've got it working in the first place of course!).

Comment: @IMSoP you're right, when I echo as XML, the tag is there. But because it's self-closing, there is nothing to send back - hence the 'undefined' in JS. Even using the `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` option, it just creates an empty set of open/close tags.

Comment: OK... so what do you expect it to do? XML and JSON are very different things, you can't just blindly convert from one to the other. The best way to send the full content of an XML document to JS is as XML; or if you want particular details, extract those details using SimpleXML and construct your own JSON document. If you [edit] the question to show more of the code you're actually trying to write, we'll have more chance of understanding your problem.

Comment: The JSON here was just for viewing the data to see what I'm working with, and how it's being interpreted.

Comment: So, the data isn't missing at all, you were just using the wrong tool to debug it? It's important to realise that SimpleXML doesn't create a big array of data, it *gives you an interface for interacting with the XML document*.

Comment: Word. Yeah, it seems it was my mistake in how I was choosing to view the data.

Comment: Soooooooooo post an answer?  How was this ever accomplished?